# Any way to stop or reduce graphical flickering on Internet Explorer caused by Ajax call (page information being updated)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

The main page of my web app has some elements, usually between 2-10 that represent clients and their current status. The information contained in each element (the info about the clients) is refreshed every 5 seconds, which pulls the information from the server via an Ajax call.

After each call, the data inside each element is updated by essentially re-adding that element to the page. Basically we add x number of elements to the page dynamically based on how much data the server returned.

It looks great in Chrome and Firefox. The data inside the elements simply updates seemlessly. In Internet Explorer there is *very* noticeable flickering on each refresh.

Is there any reliable way to fix this?

I would post some code but I'm not sure what pieces of code would exactly be relevant.

Edit: I am using an image in each of these elements, so that is being loaded in again every time there is a refresh. I tried pre-loading the image with

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var loadit = new Image().src = "/Content/bg_home_bluebox.png";
}
```

But the flickering is still the same. Don't really have any other ideas.

Comment: I don't know if bumping is a thing but I've been sort of trying to fix this since I posted this and still haven't found anything relevant/that works.

Comment: i just found an old link: [http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/flickering-ui-from-the-asp-net-ajax-toolkit-tabcontainer-while-in-an-updatepanel]. it's very old but maybe...